# What is proof of direction of Change in position vector $d \vec r$

Tags: vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier, classical-mechanics, hamilton-equations

How can I prove that the  **direction** of an infinitesimal change in position vector $\mathrm d\vec r$ is the same as that of the instantaneous velocity $ \vec v=\mathrm{d}\vec r/\mathrm{d}t$? What I found:
$$
\mathrm{d} \hat r= \left(\frac{\| \vec v \|}{\|\mathrm{d} \vec r\|} \mathrm{d}t\right)\hat v
$$ 
In this expression, the direction/unit vector $\mathrm{d}\hat r$ is related to  some multiple of direction/unit vector instantaneous velocity $ \hat v$. How can they be the same and how can we define the value of $\mathrm{d}t$?

Comment: Well, $\mathrm{d}t$ is just a scalar, and multiplication with a positive scalar does not change the direction.

Comment: Yes @Botond I know the all three quantities $ \left(\frac{\| \vec v \|}{\|\mathrm{d} \vec r\|} \mathrm{d}t\right) $ are scalars and both has same direction with positive scalar multiple.. But how we can measure $ \| \mathrm{d} \vec r\| $  and $ \mathrm{d}t $ ?

Comment: I can't really understand you. What would you like to measure?

Comment: If i take any random position vector-valued function and take first time derivative(velocity). I can calculate $ \mathrm \| \vec v \| $ but how can i calculate $ \mathrm \|{d} \vec r | \| $ and $ \mathrm {d} t $

Comment: Let  Position vector $  \vec r(x(t) , y(t)) = t^3 \hat i -2t^2 \hat j $ where $ \vec x(t)=t^3 $ and $  \vec y(t)=-2t^2 $ . Velocity $ \vec v = \frac {\mathrm{d} \vec r} {\mathrm {d} t} = 3t^2 \hat i -4t \hat j $ then we can calculate $ \mathrm \| \vec v  \| = 5 $ at $ t=1 $. How can we calculate $  \| \mathrm{d} \vec r  \| $ , $ \mathrm{d} t $ and $ \hat v $ ? These required to calculate $ \mathrm{d} \hat r $ ..